# Cannot attach Skype4Py to Skype via Python in Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, skype4py

I am on Mac OSX (10.8.2) and am trying to use Skype4py to connect to my currently running Skype instance via Python.

My difficulty here is that I have followed the instructions on the website (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Skype4Py/1.0.34#segfaults), and properly installed Skype4Py using the `arch -i386 pip install Skype4Py` command. As the instructions state, I have set my code editor's run code to use the `arch -i386 python` command to run things instead of the typical `python` (As well as tried using both to run the file directly from terminal).

My code is currently really simple (I plan to work further once I get the connection working), and is as follows:

```
import Skype4Py
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
```

That gives me an error window that python had to close as well as the following error: `Run Command: line 1: 66888 Segmentation fault: 11  arch -i386 python "$1" "${@:3}"`

After some searching around on these forums, I had found a few threads that agree upon the following code revision as an answer:

```
import Skype4Py
skype = Skype4Py.Skype(Transport='x11')
skype.Attach()
```

Unfortunately, this fix simply changes the nature of my error. The new error message is more complicated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skypeAttach.py", line 4, in <module>
    skype = Skype4Py.Skype(Transport='x11')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 250, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Skype4Py/api/darwin.py", line 296, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Skype4Py/api/__init__.py", line 214, in finalize_opts
TypeError: Unexpected option(s): Transport
```

Which, under my limited programming knowledge, seems to be trying to tell me that "Transport" is an unexpected parameter.

Comment: Try running it with `python-32` instead.

Comment: @nneonneo `Run Command: line 1: python-32: command not found` .. I also have since tried `arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6` Which leads to the error of: `No module named Skype4Py`

Comment: Hm? `python-32` should be in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.x/bin`; it comes with the python.org distribution of Python (which I recommend using).

Comment: @nneonneo I used the installer found at python.org/download titled "Python 3.3.0 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer." And I don't have the "2.x" folder in my Versions folder, only the "3.3.0" folder.

Comment: @nneonneo I am going to try version 2.7, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Skype4Py PyPI page:

> It works on Windows, OSX and Linux platforms with Python 2.x versions.

It is not compatible with Python 3.3. Try installing it with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a shell script to force 32-bit mode:

```
#!/bin/bash
arch -i386 /usr/bin/python ./sendMessage.py
```